# Bootstrap form-group

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I got two inputs inside a form-group, from bootstrap framework. My problem is if the first name gives error, the second name will give aswell the same error that gives on first name, and that is not what I want, how can I can avoid this problem?

```
<form id="containerForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">First name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
        </div>
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Last name</label>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I got a required in the inputs, with bootstrap i can get a personalized message, saying "Please this field cant be empty" if the user dont put anything on that input...

Comment: This is the normal HTML behavior while using the required attribute. If you want to customize this you have to use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but there are more post on Stackoverflow.com about this item.

Anyway as I always do I advise you to use server-side validation

```
But just to get you going see this example:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2zbgge3/1/